# How to replace data and output an array?

Tags: php

It is necessary to substitute the data from the $user array inside the %id% ... of the $templates array. As I understand it, you need to do this through regular expressions, but I have no experience in this matter. I tried to substitute the data through preg replace, but it didn't work out very well.

```
/*
  task
  1. Write a definition specification that matches a data template from a set of objects.
*/


class Api
{
  public function __construct()
  {

  }


  /**
   *
   * @param       array $array
   * @param       string $template
   * @return      string
   */
  public function get_api_path(array $array, string $template) : string
  {
      $result = '';

      /* Code */

      return $result;
  }
}

$user =
  [
      'id'        => 20,
      'name'      => 'John Dow',
      'role'      => 'QA',
      'salary'    => 100
  ];

$api_path_templates =
  [
      "/api/items/%id%/%name%",
      "/api/items/%id%/%role%",
      "/api/items/%id%/%salary%"
  ];

$api = new Api();

$api_paths = array_map(function ($api_path_template) use ($api, $user)
{
  return $api->get_api_path($user, $api_path_template);
}, $api_path_templates);

echo json_encode($api_paths, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$expected_result = ['/api/items/20/John%20Dow','/api/items/20/QA','/api/items/20/100'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple `str_replace()` in a loop over `$api_path_templates`

```
$user =
  [
      'id'        => 20,
      'name'      => 'John Dow',
      'role'      => 'QA',
      'salary'    => 100
  ];

$api_path_templates =
  [
      "/api/items/%id%/%name%",
      "/api/items/%id%/%role%",
      "/api/items/%id%/%salary%"
  ];

foreach ( $api_path_templates as $k=>&$a){
    $a = str_replace('%id%', $user['id'], $a);
    $a = str_replace('%name%', $user['name'], $a);
    $a = str_replace('%role%', $user['role'], $a);
    $a = str_replace('%salary%', $user['salary'], $a);
}
print_r($api_path_templates);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => /api/items/20/John Dow
    [1] => /api/items/20/QA
    [2] => /api/items/20/100
)
```